# I got "Type Mismatch" error in multiple condition scenario ( case function is used)

Tags: excel, vba, case

I am trying to do a vba code for multiple conditions and selection scenario.
Column AR is the column I would like to show the result of the selection.
My selection logic is:

```
If Column E (cells(m,5)) equals "Not IBC", then put value in the cell in AR (cells(m,44)) as "Exclude"
If Column AQ (cells(m,43)) equals "Yes", then put value in the cell in AR (cells(m,44)) as "Exclude"
If Column W (cells(m,23)) equals "X" or "Y", then put value in the cell in AR (cells(m,44)) as "Exclude"
If Column G (cells(m,7)) equals "A" or "B" or "C" and Column I (cells(m,9)) is not equal to "1.1" nor "1.2", then put value in the cell in AR (cells(m,44)) as "Exclude"
Rest would give AR as Include
```

My actual code is

However, I am given Type Mismatch Error even I changed the cell type to General.

Is there a way to remove the Type Mismatch Error or if my code is correct based on the logic?

Thank you!

```
Sub inclusion()

Columns("AR:AR").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, _
      CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
      Columns("AR:AR").Cells(1, 1) = "Include?"

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With Range("G:G")  '
        .NumberFormat = "General"
        .Value = .Value
        .NumberFormat = "0"
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

With Range("I:I")  '
        .NumberFormat = "General"
        .Value = .Value
        .NumberFormat = "0"
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Dim lastRow4 As Long
    lastRow4 = Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Dim legacy As String
Dim tax As String
Dim inclusion As String
Dim IBC As String
Dim pact As String
Dim agg As String

Dim m As Long
For m = 2 To lastRow4

legacy = Cells(m, 7)
tax = Cells(m, 9)
IBC = Cells(m, 5)
pact = Cells(m, 23)
agg = Cells(m, 43)


Select Case True

Case IBC = "Not IBC"
inclusion = "Exclude"

Case agg = "Yes"
inclusion = "Exclude"

Case (pact = "X" Or Impact = "Y")
inclusion = "Exclude"

Case (legacy = "A" Or legacy = "B" Or legacy = "C") And tax <> "1.1" And tax <> "1.2"
                inclusion = "Exclude"
Case Else
inclusion = "Include"

Cells(m, 44) = inclusion
End Select

Next m

End Sub
```

Comment: On which line(s) do you get the error?  A good start would be to add `Option Explicit` at the top of your code module, and then to fix all of your variable name mismatches (IBC/IHC, agg/Aggregation, pact/Impact)

Comment: I'm guessing it's because `tax` is a numeric value and you're treating it like a string. But, as Tim said, when the error occurs it tells you exactly which line is causing it, and you should provide that information in your post.

Comment: Your Select block is rather strange, it looks like it works, but its odd!

Comment: It also might be because you declare a variable named `IBC`, which you also use in the `SELECT`, but you never assign a value to it - you assign to `IHC` instead.

Comment: Thanks! VBA did not really tell me where it has error, the variable name mismatch is fixed even after that. I changed the name to adapt to it. Tax has more than 1.1 in reality. It is like 1.1 XXXX (text message).